# How to implement "fill in the blanks" ? reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to implement *"fill in the blanks"* in reactjs. I have tried the code below, but I think its not a good idea, because they can inspect element of it.

Is there a better implementation of this? And also is it possible to display a hint (at least one letter in the blank)? thanks.

```css
.blank {
  color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>Nunc ac <span class="blank">imperdiet</span> justo</div>
```

Comment: Where is the react code?

Comment: @brk i put the snippet Sir. should I translate that *small* code to reactjs?